# How to extract velocity vectors of pixels from cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

Can anybody help me to get the velocity information of each pixel from OpenCV's `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK`?

Comment: How is this any different from [your other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16672003/1601291)

Comment: this time am trying to use goodFeaturesToTrack with cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK but the previous one uses calcOpticalFlowFarneback and i didn't get the result i was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp) that is also available with the openCV code.

A superquick summary:

calcOpticalFlowPyrLK is sparse so it needs points to calculate the optical flow from.
use `goodFeaturesToTrack` to initialize the points ( takes an image and an empty point vector as input (plus some parameters available in the documentation) )

Then use `cornerSubPix` to refine point positions (takes an image and a full point vector (plus other params))

Finally load a new image and run `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` on the points you have initialized on the previous one (takes two images (this and previous) and a full and empty point vector (corresponding to points in the previous image and this one). (you probably won't need to initialize points for the next image, but rather use the ones that calcOpticalFlowPyrLK provided)

The difference in point position divided by the time between images gives you the velocity.

But do look at the example for details

Comment: Thanks Kamjagi for your help. another Q can we get the optical flow of all pixels in the frame or only for those considered as good featured by goodFeaturesToTrack?

Comment: Dear Kamjagi, just to make it clear what i want to do it to display the optical flow/ speed of all pixels of a frame in the video.

Comment: Then you are describing a dense problem rather than a sparse one, so calcOpticalFlowPyrLK is not the way to go. Take a look at createOptFlow_DualTVL1  and this example for dense OF https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tvl1_optical_flow.cpp

Comment: Kamjagin, thanks sooooooo much it is exactly what i was looking for. i still have to customize to my scope and i will came back if i have any Q in doing that. Thanks all for you help. RESPECT!!!

Comment: Thanks. Just try to write better questions in the future (explaining the problem and what you have tried so far).

Comment: Hi Kamjagin, one issue i have here is it is extremely slow. tvl1->calc(Previous_Gray, Current_Gray, Optical_Flow); this function take about 20 sec every time. is it normal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dense things are slow :). Take a look at the various GPU implementations. (Opencv has farneback and gpu::PyrLKOpticalFlow::dense as far as I know)